# Can I capture the return value of a 'for' statement in a variable without using 'eval'?

Tags: javascript, eval

Javascript's `for` statement returns `undefined`, at least when I use it in Chromium's JS repl:

```
> for (i=0;i<1;i++);
: undefined
```

Therefore, I would expect the following statement to interpret thusly:

```
> a = for (i=0;i<1;i++);
: undefined
```

Instead I get

```
a = for (i=0;i<1;i++);
VM488:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for
```

The only workaround I can think of is `a = eval("for (i=0;i<1;i++);")`, which does work. However, as my question states, I want to do this *without* using `eval`. Is it possible?

Comment: Statements return nothing (by definition).

Comment: `for` statements don't evaluate to a value at all. You're seeing `undefined` because you ran code which does not return a value. Even running that code with `eval` [results in a syntax error](https://jsfiddle.net/7sav8zb9/1/)

Comment: `Is it possible?` --- sure `var a = undefined; for (i=0;i<1;i++);`

Comment: which value do you expect?

Comment: `eval("a = for (i=0;i<1;i++);")` gives me `SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'for'` in Firefox.

Comment: @FelixKling Oops! Sorry, meant to say a = eval(...). Updated question, thanks!

Comment: @MikeCluck Oops, I meant to format it like, a = eval(...), which DOES assign undefined to variable a. Updated code in question! Thanks

Comment: @alejandroalvarado Ahh, makes more sense. Still, you're getting `undefined` because no value is being returned from `eval`. Are you exclusively trying to get `undefined` or are you hoping to get some other kind of "return value" from a `for` loop?

Comment: @MikeCluck I am expecting it to return undefined. Here is my actual code: `i=(h)=>eval("for(a=0,b=1;h--;b=a+(a=b));")||a`

I want to do this but without eval(). My motivation is I'm playing code golf with a friend, haha.

Comment: The duplicate should answer your question, and provides a better example. The short answer is: No, there is no way to get the "implicit" return value of a statement/loop without `eval`.

Comment: @alejandroalvarado The problem is that `for` statements do not evaluate to *any* value. Not even `undefined`. `eval`, on the other hand, returns `undefined` when given code that does not evaluate to a value or, of course, code that evaluates to `undefined`

Comment: @FelixKling Wow, awesome, thanks for the prompt help. Appreciate everyone who commented, learned something today!

Comment: @MikeCluck Welp, guess that answers my question then. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike: That's not quite right. See the duplicate and try `for (i=0;i<3; i++) i;` in the console. But sure, they are not expressions, so if that's what you mean then that's correct.

Comment: Long story short: Any "procedure" in JavaScript returns some result (a *completion record*), mainly for control flow purposes (e.g. was an error thrown in the loop body). These kind of results can usually not be accessed directly. However, evaluating an expression basically means unwrapping the result to get actual value. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-completion-record-specification-type

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, I got you. I was just meaning that `for` loops are not expressions so they don't have an accessible value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the for statement allowed you to iterate over a collection of items, which mean will be executing an instruction between the body of the `for` an example:

```
for (i=0;i<1;i++){
  //this is the body
  console.log(i);
}
```

the for statement doesn't return a value, what you are seeing is the dev chrome  tools returning undefined.

read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

what you might want to do is:

```
var myValues = []; // an array
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
  values.push(i)
}

console.log(values); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: *"of all function in javascript return undefined."* But there is no function here.

Comment: I specifically want to put undefined inside of a variable AS A RESULT of a for statement, which can be done using eval() (as mentioned in question). My question is how to do it without resorting to eval()!

Comment: @FelixKling I presume he meant to say all statements in JS return undefined?

Comment: This answer is not quite right. Just try `for (i=0;i<3;i++) i;` in the console. See the duplicate of more info.